Extension of the Equality Case for Functions in the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality
Let $f,g\in C(\mathbb R,\mathbb R)$, with the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have :
$$\forall x\ge 0, \left(\int_{0}^{x} fg\right)^2 \le \left(\int_{0}^{x} f^2\right) \times \left(\int_{0}^{x} g^2\right)$$
with the equality case in $[0,x]$ (where $x\neq 0$) iff : $\exists \alpha \in \mathbb R, \forall t\in [0,x], f(t) = \alpha g(t)$.
What could happened if $x$ tends to $0$ ? I wanted to extend the case of the equality in this situation.
Imagine if $\left(\int_{0}^{x} fg\right)^2 / \left(\int_{0}^{x} f^2 \times \int_{0}^{x} g^2\right)$ tends to $1$. 
Just by extending the equality case, I thought that it is only possible iff $f/g$ tends to a constant near $0$.
It is the same as saying :
$$\left(\int_{0}^{x} fg\right)^2 \sim_{x\to 0} \left(\int_{0}^{x} f^2\right) \times \left(\int_{0}^{x} g^2\right)\tag{0}\label{eq0}$$
Iff $\exists\alpha \in \mathbb R, f\sim_{x\to0}\alpha g$.
I tried with a few example, it seems to work. However, how to prove this or to disprove this ? 
I thought of using the proof of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.
NB : $f \sim_{x\to 0} g \iff f(x)-g(x) = o_{x\to 0}(g(x))$
EDIT $1$ : Suppose that $\exists \alpha \in \mathbb R^* $ such that $f\sim_{x\to0}\alpha g$ :
\begin{align}
\left(\int_{0}^x fg\right)^2  & = \alpha^2\left(\int_{0}^x (g^2 + o(g^2))\right)^2 \\ & = \alpha^2\left(\left(\int_{0}^x g^2\right)^2 + \left(\int_{0}^x o(g^2)\right)^2 + 2\int_{0}^x o(g^2)\times\int_{0}^x g^2\right) \\
 & = \alpha^2\left(\int_{0}^x g^2\right)^2 + o\left(\left(\int_{0}^x g^2\right)^2\right) \tag{1}\label{eq1}\\ 
 \int_{0}^x f^2 & = \alpha^2\int_{0}^x g^2 + \int_{0}^x o(g)^2 + \int_{0}^x o(g^2)   \\
 & = \alpha^2\int_{0}^x g^2 + \int_{0}^x o(g^2) \tag{2}\label{eq2}\\ 
 & = \alpha^2\int_{0}^x g^2 + o\left(\int_{0}^x g^2\right)\tag{3}\label{eq3}
\end{align}
Which gives us $\eqref{eq0}$.
To explain \eqref{eq1} and \eqref{eq3}, suppose that $f(x) =_{x\to 0} o(g(x))$ and $g$ is positive. 
Let $\varepsilon > 0$ and $\delta > 0$ such that $\forall t \in ]-\delta, \delta[, |f(t)| < \varepsilon |g(t)|$.  
So, $\forall x \in [0, \delta[$ :
\begin{align}
\left|\int_{0}^x f\right|  & \le \varepsilon \int_{0}^x |g| = \varepsilon \left|\int_{0}^x g\right|
\end{align}
So : $$\boxed{f(x) =_{x\to 0} o(g(x)) \text{ and } g\ge 0 \implies \int_{0}^x f =_{x\to 0} o\left(\int_{0}^x g\right)}$$
To explain \eqref{eq2}, if we have $f(x) =_{x\to 0} o(g(x))$ then $f(x)^2 =_{x\to 0} o(g(x))^2$.
But : $f(x)^2/g(x)^2 = (f(x)/g(x))^2 \to 0$ so $\boxed{o(g)^2 =_{x\to 0} o(g^2)}$.
Now it leaves us the other part.

I guess you mean "suppose that $f(x) \color{red }\sim_{x\to 0} o(g(x))$" instead of suppose that $f(x) \color{red}=_{x\to 0} o(g(x))$.

In the initial inequality, the equality case for $\int_0^x\cdot dt$ and $x=0$ holds always rather than when $\exists\alpha\in\mathbb R,\forall t\in [0,x], f(t)=\alpha g(t)$, in particular, when $g(0)=0\ne f(0)$.

Use the fact that if a function $h$ is continuous, then
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{x}\int_0^x h(t),dt = h(0).
$$

Generally false, for several reasons.
The first counter-example is inspired by the theory of regularly varying functions. Consider $g(x) = 1$ and $f(x) = \ln(x)$. Check that
$$ \int_0^x f = x (\ln x-1) \quad , \quad \int_0^x f^2 = x ((\ln x)^2 - 2 \ln x +2) .$$
It follows that
$ (\int_0^x fg)^2 / (\int_0^x f^2 \int_0^x g^2) \to 1 $
as $x\to 0$, but $f/g \to -\infty$.
Another counter-example, using functions that are continuous on $[0,\infty)$, is given by $g(x) = x$ and $f(x) = x \ln x$. You can easily extend them to functions in $C(\mathbb R, \mathbb R)$.
The second counter-example comes from the usual technique of taking "nice" functions, and then perturbing them in a way that does not significantly change their integral, but that does break the convergence of their ratio.
Let us construct an explicit example where $(\int_0^x fg)^2 / (\int_0^x f^2 \int_0^x g^2)$ converges to $1$ as $x\to 0$ but where $f/g$ does not converge. For simplicity, start with $g(x) = x$ for every $x\geq 0$.
Define for every $n\geq 3$ the function
$$ h_n(x) = \max\left( 0 \ , \ 1- n^3\left|x-\frac{1}{n}\right| \right). $$
This function is continuous and equals $0$ outside of $[\frac 1 n - \frac 1 {n^3} , \frac 1 n + \frac 1 {n^3}]$, and $\int_0^\infty h_n = n^{-3}$.
Now let $f(x) = x(1-\sum_{n\geq 3} h_n(x))$. Since for every $n\geq 3$ we have $(f/g)(1/n) = 0$ and $(f/g)(1/(n+1/2))=1$, clearly $f/g$ cannot converge as $x\to 0$. However, for every $\frac 1 {n+1} + \frac 1 {(n+1)^3} \leq x \leq \frac 1 n - \frac 1 {n^3}$ we have
$$ \left| \int_0^x t f(t)\mathrm{d} t - \int_0^x t^2 \mathrm{d}t \right| \leq \mathrm{cste}\ \sum_{k\geq n+1} k^{-5} \leq \mathrm{cste}\ x^4$$
and
$$\left| \int_0^x f^2 - \int_0^x t^2 \mathrm{d}t \right| \leq \mathrm{cste}\ \sum_{k\geq n+1} k^{-5} \leq \mathrm{cste}\ x^4. $$
We can extend this bound to every $x\leq 1/3$; hence $(\int_0^x fg)^2 / ( \int_0^x f^2 \int_0^x g^2)$ converges to $1$.

In the first example $f\not\in C(\mathbb R,\mathbb R)$.

Indeed, which is why I added the case $f(x) = x \ln x$ in this example to make it continuous. I left the non-continuous $f$ because the computations are nicer, and the idea really is the same.

I tried to use one of proofs of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, but unsuccessfully. Below is my attempt.
To avoid the trivial case we suppose that there exists no $\varepsilon\ne 0$ such that ($f(t)=0$ for each $t$ between $\varepsilon$ and $0$) or ($g(t)=0$ for each $t$ between $\varepsilon$ and $0$) because otherwise
$$\left(\int_{0}^{x} f(t)g(t)dt\right)^2 =0= \left(\int_{0}^{x} f(t)^2dt\right) \cdot \left(\int_{0}^{x} g(t)^2dt\right)$$
for each $x$ between $\varepsilon$ and $0$ and each $f\in C(\mathbb R,\mathbb R)$.
Then $\int_{0}^{x} f(t)^2dt$ and $\int_{0}^{x} g(t)^2dt$ are nonzeroes for each $x\ne 0$. Therefore
$$\int_{0}^{x} f(t)^2dt-\frac{\left(\int_{0}^{x} f(t)g(t)dt\right)^2}{\int_{0}^{x} g(t)^2dt}=$$
$$\int_{0}^{x} f(t)^2dt-2\frac{\left(\int_{0}^{x} f(s)g(s)ds\right)^2}{\int_{0}^{x} g(s)^2ds}+
\frac{\left(\int_{0}^{x} f(s)g(s)ds\right)^2}{\int_{0}^{x} g(s)^2ds}=$$
$$\int_{0}^{x} \left( f(t)-g(t)\frac{\int_{0}^{x} f(s)g(s)ds}{\int_{0}^{x} g(s)^2ds}  \right)^2dt.$$
Therefore
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\left(\int_{0}^{x} f(t)g(t)dt\right)^2-\left(\int_{0}^{x} f(t)^2dt\right) \cdot \left(\int_{0}^{x} g(t)^2dt\right)}{\left(\int_{0}^{x} f(t)^2dt\right) \cdot \left(\int_{0}^{x} g(t)^2dt\right)}=0$$ iff
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\int_{0}^{x}\left( f(t)-g(t)\frac{\int_{0}^{x} f(s)g(s)ds}{\int_{0}^{x} g(s)^2ds}  \right)^2dt}{\int_{0}^{x} f(t)^2dt}=0.$$
Note that in order to provide the sense to $f\sim_{x\to 0}\alpha g$ (for some real $\alpha$) we need to assume that there exists $\varepsilon'>0$ such that $g(x)\ne 0$ for each $x\in (-\varepsilon',\varepsilon')\setminus \{0\}$.
